# Why can't Ellipsis and NotImplemented be pickled?

Tags: python, pickle

I was surprised to find that python (version 3.2.2) was refusing to pickle an object because its dict contained a reference to `Ellipsis`.  Of the other [built-in constants](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/constants.html), pickle is happy working with `False`, `True`, and `None`, as explicitly stated in the [pickle documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/pickle.html?highlight=pickle#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled), but also chokes on `NotImplemented`.

```
Python 3.2.2 (default, Sep  5 2011, 21:17:14) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.dumps(True)
b'\x80\x03\x88.'
>>> pickle.dumps(False)
b'\x80\x03\x89.'
>>> pickle.dumps(None)
b'\x80\x03N.'
>>> pickle.dumps(Ellipsis)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'ellipsis'>: attribute lookup builtins.ellipsis failed
>>> pickle.dumps(NotImplemented)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'NotImplementedType'>: attribute lookup builtins.NotImplementedType failed
```

For completeness, of the less useful built-in constants, `__debug__` is just a bool, so causes no problems; `copyright`, `license`, and `credits` work (their type is `site._Printer`); `quit` and `exit` do not (their type is `site.Quitter`, which can't be found as it is defined inside a function).

Can anyone explain why this is - surely `Ellipsis` and `NotImplemented` haven't just been overlooked?  The only relevant information I can find is [this bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue6477), which complains that `NoneType` (i.e., `type(None)`) is not picklable.  One of the commenters mentions that `type(Ellipsis)` and `type(NotImplemented)` cannot be pickled, apparently without noticing that their instances cannot be either.

Comment: Odd omission, though one could argue you're not really supposed to keep references to those values to begin with.

Comment: @Inderdial: my particular use case was in a container that keeps track of slices that have been accessed.  Since slices can be pickled, it seems strange that Ellipsis (which is really just a special kind of slice) cannot.  Storing a reference to `NotImplemented` is probably less likely to be useful, though I can imagine somebody might want it for some kind of complicated comparison scheme.

Comment: @James - Strictly speaking, `Ellipsis` is not a special kind of slice, but its interpretation is absolutely user-defined.  In Numpy, it is more like a sequence of zero or more slices, determined automatically.

Answer (score 5):

There is absolutely no reason for python not to pickle things like `Ellipsis` and `NotImplemented`, and frankly not having them picklable contributes to the frailty of python as a parallel / asynchronous language.  You can pickle these types of objects with `dill`, a replacement for `pickle`.  Yes, I'm aware this is a mild rant, but I think a `NotImplemented` in your target code should not stop you from using `multiprocessing` or some other from of parallel python… or saving the state of your python session for use at a later time… or whatever.

```
Python 3.2.5 (default, May 19 2013, 14:25:55) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill
>>> dill.dumps(True)
b'\x80\x03\x88.'
>>> dill.dumps(False)
b'\x80\x03\x89.'
>>> dill.dumps(None)
b'\x80\x03N.'
>>> dill.dumps(Ellipsis)
b'\x80\x03cdill.dill\n_eval_repr\nq\x00X\x08\x00\x00\x00Ellipsisq\x01\x85q\x02Rq\x03.'
>>> dill.dumps(NotImplemented)
b'\x80\x03cdill.dill\n_eval_repr\nq\x00X\x0e\x00\x00\x00NotImplementedq\x01\x85q\x02Rq\x03.'
```

Get `dill` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill

Comment: Thanks for this-- it got me looking and I found this link which helped me solve my problem parallelizing in IPython: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/anonymous/5241793

Comment: @GB: awesome.  That's a good link you posted.  I'm also aware of `dill` being used as a pickle replacement in `multiprocessing`, `mpi4py`, and some other of the python packages used in parallel computing.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled):

> The following types can be pickled:
>
> - None, True, and False
> - integers, floating point numbers, complex numbers
> - strings, bytes, bytearrays
> - tuples, lists, sets, and dictionaries containing only picklable objects
> - functions defined at the top level of a module
> - built-in functions defined at the top level of a module
> - classes that are defined at the top level of a module
> - instances of such classes whose __dict__ or __setstate__() is picklable (see section   Pickling Class Instances for details)

The two objects in question, `Ellipsis` and `NotImplemented`, do not conform to any of these rules, and consequently cannot be pickled.

I doubt that there is any better reason for not including all built-in constants in the first rule other than that nobody has seen the need for it.  If you really think pickle should support that, consider posting a feature request (better bring a convincing use case!).

Comment: I saw that list, but wasn't sure whether it was exclusive.  In particular, builtin functions like `map` and `open` can be pickled, but don't seem to fit any of those criteria (unless you consider them to be 'defined at the top level of a module', in which case it seems odd that the likes of `NoneType` cannot be pickled).

Comment: `map` and `open` are defined at the top level of the `__builtin__` module (try `import __builtin__ as B; B.map`), `NoneType` is a built-in class, not a function.  The documentation seems consistent to me!

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense - thanks for the explanation (though now I'm wondering where NoneType is defined, if anywhere!).  Though I really wanted to know what the reasoning behind this behaviour is - maybe I should just submit a bug report.